# How to bind TextBox from DropdownList in ASP NET without page refresh

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have a dropdownlist control and a text box control in asp.net. dropdownlist is getting data from database. suppose some data are x-ray,USG,MRI and their value are 100,200,300. So if i select x-ray from the dropdown i want it's value 100 binds at the textbox without page refresh. How can i do this??? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Using .net, to have something happen on the server side when something is selected from DropDownList, having property AutoPostBack=true is required. This means when you change the SelectedIndex, the page refreshes (postback), then the SelectedIndexChanged event is fired.

Theres a few approaches. In your page_load event, put everything you want to happen on the first page load in `If Not IsPostBack Then ... End If` block. Then when a PostBack happens, like DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged, the code in `If Not IsPostBack Then` won't happen, because it IS a postback.

The above approach still has a page reload, but you can choose what happens when its this type of PostBack page reload. You may have javascript thats re-firing, though...

The second approach would be to have no postback event happen from the dropdownlist, and handle the Binding of the selected item in DropDownList to the TextBox with javascript.